# Moving UITextField that is located under keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitextfield, uikeyboard

so like im sure every iOS programmer i ran into a problem, when trying to have a page full of UITextFields, it became evident that when the keyboard comes up it covers half of them. So i went to Apple's documentation and read all about it and wrote up the code for it, but it isn't working for me. Every time i run the view it crashes. Thanks in advance for your help.

`.h` file

```
 @interface NewUserViewController : UIViewController{

   } 

    - (IBAction)signMeUpButtonPressed:(id)sender;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *activeField;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *contentScrollView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstNameLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameInput;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastNameLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastNameInput;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameInput;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *emailLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailInput;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *passwordLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *setPasswordInput;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *reenterPasswordLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *checkSetPasswordInput;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *signMeUpButton;
```

All are connected to their outlets (except for active field. Im not sure where it belongs or what it should be connected to)

`.m` file

```
@implementation NewUserViewController

@synthesize contentScrollView;
@synthesize activeField;
@synthesize firstNameLabel, lastNameLabel, usernameLabel, emailLabel, passwordLabel, reenterPasswordLabel;
@synthesize firstNameInput, lastNameInput, usernameInput, emailInput, setPasswordInput, checkSetPasswordInput;
@synthesize backButton, signMeUpButton;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
activeField = nil;
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    contentScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    contentScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [contentScrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    contentScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    contentScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (IBAction)signMeUpButtonPressed:(id)sender {
}
```

Comment: If you get a crash, make sure to post the relevant output for the crash to help us figure out what went wrong. It's pretty difficult to spot where the crash is happening without more info on it :)

Comment: You need to add your controls in scroll panel and use scrolling to show the controls when keyboard appears.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NewUserViewController 0xa1972b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key firstNameLable.'

Comment: not sure i know what you mean amrit_neo

Comment: I was able to fix the crash, but it doesn't scroll still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {



    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];
//offset is global
    offset = contentScrollView.contentOffset;

    CGRect viewFrame = contentScrollView.frame;
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height;
    contentScrollView.frame = viewFrame;

    UITextField *current = (UITextField *)[self findFirstResponder];
    CGRect textFieldRect = current.frame;

    [contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

}
- (UIView *)findFirstResponder {
    for (UIView *subView in  scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isFirstResponder]){
            return subView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void) keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {

//scrollViewFrame is global the first frame of you scrollview
    contentScrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame;

    contentScrollView.contentOffset =offset;


}
```

this is not a complete code this is just a little logic of performing what you want to do.